# Unable to change spy returnValue in Jasmine tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm having a hard time understanding why I'm unable to change the return value of a mock service function using `and.returnValue()` as mentioned in [the Jasmine docs](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/spying_on_properties). I've simplified my test file to demonstrate my mocking strategy, but the gist of it is that on component initialization I need `StateService.getUserId()` to return either an example string, or an empty string. I set the return value for it initially as '1234', but in my test I need to have it return an empty string to test some other conditions.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let comp: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  let mockStateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StateService', {
    getUserId: '1234',
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [
        // .....
        [{ provide: StateService, useValue: mockStateService }],
      ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('OnInit', () => {
    it('should do some other things when userId doesnt exist', () => {
      mockStateService.getUserId.and.returnValue('');
      fixture.detectChanges(); // not sure I need this, but removing it doesn't fix the issue either

      expect(comp.userId).toBe('');
    });
  });
});
```

The above test always fails because userId is always the initial return value of the spy '1234', even after telling it to return an empty string in the test.

state.service.ts:

```
getUserId = () => {
  return this.userId;
};
```

my.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.userId = this.stateService.getUserId();

  if (!this.userId ) {
    // ......
  } else {
    // ......
  }
}
```

Comment: You're changing the return value from the test double _after_ `ngOnInit` has been called.

Comment: I'm calling fixture.detectChanges() after changing the return value, which I would expect to work since it retriggers ngOnInit. Do you know how you'd be able to dynamically change the return value in beforeEach prior to the ngOnInit?

Comment: detectChanges would only call ngOnInit the first time it is run. you can call ngOnInit manualy in the test, or you can skip calling detectChanges in beforeEach

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter stated, running `detectChanges()` should run `ngOnInit()` before you set the value of the mock.  Changing the value in the mock would not cause `ngOnInit() to rerun on the next` detectChanges()`.

That said, I did notice something that struck me as odd.

In your real code `getUserId` is a method:

```
getUserId = () => {
  return this.userId;
};
```

In your mock, `getUserId` is a property:

```
  let mockStateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StateService', {
    getUserId: '1234',
  });
```

So, I'd change the mock to use a method:

```
  let mockStateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StateService', {
    getUserId = () => {
      return '1234';
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, when I change the mock to be a method I get the error "this.stateService.getUserId(...).subscribe is not a function"